# Content organizer document routing issues (Sharepoint 2013)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, content, content-organizer-rule

I have three libraries set up on another Site collection that I have routing to the records management site, and I need the three libraries routed to different places on the record management site.  My current issue is they keep going into the same library on the record management site.  I have the sendto connections all set up for the three pointing to the Records management site.  I also have the content organizer rules set for the three libraries to do go to their respective location on the records management site.  So I do not know what the heck I am doing wrong.

Can anyone offer any suggestions on how do get the library docs doing where I want them to?

Here is a pic of my content organizer rule for the library on the source site.
[image]

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: What content type is attached to the documents from the three libraries? Can you show your organizer rule

Comment: Added a screen shot in my post for you.